# Strange error while deleting a file using the module fs in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to delete some files in a folder using the module fs.
I need to delete a file only if it is older (modified time) that 1 minute.
But I get a strange error.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var files = fs.readdirSync("./folder");
for (var i in files) {
  fs.stat("./folder/" + files[i], function (err, stats) {
    var currentTimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    var fileTimestamp = Math.round((new Date(stats.mtime).getTime() / 1000));
    if ((currentTimestamp - fileTimestamp) > 60 * 1) {
      //Elimino il file di cache
      fs.unlinkSync("./folder/" + files[i], function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("File deleted");
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Unfortunately I get this error

```
fs.js:765
  return binding.unlink(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
```

Why does this happen?
How can I solve ??
Thanks

---

EDIT

---

I make a log before the `fs.unlinkSync("./folder/" + files[i], function (err)` and I see that is called 2 times with the same file... but there is only one file in the folder.... with that name

Comment: Better if you include the stack trace

Comment: how can you give a `callback` when are you using `unlinkSync` ? It should be `unlink` if you want a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the problem:-

You are doing `fs.stat` *an async call* in `for loop`. And `for` is a `sync` block. There are chances that it will be called after the end of your `for` loop. In the end, it will call all callbacks with last value of `i`.

Since value of `i` is same it will search for the same file more than once and it will end up throwing an error.

There are two solutions to your problem.

**1)** Use `fs.statSync` & `fs.unlinkSync` so it will be sync call. The value of `i` won't increment until the whole loop executes, but it's not the good way of doing it.

**2)** Use `Array.forEach` because it is an `async` process, so it will call the function on each file. I will prefer this method.

I've modified your problem and got it working with `Array.forEach`.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var files = fs.readdirSync("./Folder");

var deleteFile = function (fileName) {
    fs.stat("./Folder/" + fileName, function (err, stats) {
       var currentTimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
       var fileTimestamp = Math.round((new Date(stats.mtime).getTime() / 1000));
       if ((currentTimestamp - fileTimestamp) > 60 * 1) {
           //Elimino il file di cache
           console.log('deleting ',fileName)
           fs.unlink("./Folder/" + fileName, function (err) {
              if (err) {
                 console.log(err);
             } else {
                console.log("File deleted");
            }
           });
       }
   });
}

files.forEach(deleteFile);
```