# node.js fs write files in bluk

Tags: node.js, fs

In node.js I have an array called jobs which I push file locations and images to. This happens 112 times every 13 seconds (each image/location is unique)

```
   jobs.push(['/home/user/public_html/img/'+filename+'.png',canvas[n].toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,"")]);
```

Then I loop through all the jobs and write the files with fs

```
for(var job=0;job<jobs.length;job++){
    fs.writeFile(jobs[job][0],(new Buffer(jobs[job][1],'base64')));
    }
```

My question is; Can the file writing loop be done quicker?

This way the files are wrote to one after the other. I think it would be better to do them all at the same time **since this happens only once per 13 seconds as a server job**

could multiple instances of fs help?

```
var fs1=require('fs');
var fs2=require('fs');
var fs3=require('fs');
```

Or webworkers?? (I don't know about this in node)

Comment: Node is async.  Your loop doesn't even wait for the files to be written.

Comment: I read fs.writeFile without a callback will cause no code to be executed until it is done!?

Comment: That is not true.  https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L979

Comment: have a look here, seems same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705002/strange-error-while-deleting-a-file-using-the-module-fs-in-node-js/24709262#24709262

Comment: Ok thanks @Mritunjay for Array.forEach and to SLaks for highlighting my misconception but my question is how to speed the bulk file-writing up by doing them all at once? child_processes look interesting!? It just seems a bit weak that fs must only focus on one file at a time!

Answer (score 0):

> Node uses the Worker Pool to handle "expensive" tasks. This includes I/O for which an operating system does not provide a non-blocking version, as well as particularly CPU-intensive tasks.
>
> These are the Node module APIs that make use of this Worker Pool:
>
> I/O-intensive
> DNS: dns.lookup(), dns.lookupService().
> File System: All file system APIs except fs.FSWatcher() and those that are explicitly synchronous use libuv's threadpool.

© https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/